# Qual é o erro na Lógica?

Tags: c, algoritmo, lógica

Dados os valores de `x` real e `n` natural positivo, calcular:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float x = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
    int soma = 0;
    int fat = 1;

    printf("Digite um valor:");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("Digite a quantidade de operações:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        soma = (x + i)/fat;
        fat = fat * i;
}
    printf("A soma n pra S = x+n/n!\nÉ: %d", soma);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pergunta: a soma possui apenas 4 termos mesmo ou deverão ser somados todos os termos entre 3 e n também? Da forma que você postou pula do 3 para o n.

Comment: E não deveria ser `soma += (x + i)/fat`? Da forma que fez você sobrescreve o valor a cada iteração.

Comment: A soma dos termos começa do 1 até o n que é a quantidade de termos escolhida por exemplo 5, foi até o 3 pra mostrar como seria desde o início do cálculo

Comment: Anderson apliquei o operador de atribuição por adição que faltava, mas ainda continua com um resultado errado

Comment: Marvin, tem certeza que `soma` será sempre um número inteiro?

Comment: Já mudei o tipo para aceitar valores floats, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Três coisas:

1. Você sobrescrever o valor de `soma` a cada iteração do laço;
2. Você define `soma` como inteiro;
3. Você primeiro deve multiplicar o `fat`, depois somar;

Para corrigir o (1), precisará mudar de `soma =` para `soma +=`. Já para corrigir o (2) basta definir `soma` como `float`. O item (3) precisa ser feito pois senão você terá 2 vezes o denominador igual a 1. `fat` começa em 1, gerando o termo (x+1)/1!, depois ele é multiplicado por `i` que também é 1, gerando na próxima iteração (x+2)/1!. Na próxima ficaria (x+3)/2!, etc. Ou seja, o resultado seria diferente do esperado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float x = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
    float soma = 0;
    int fat = 1;

    printf("Digite um valor:");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("Digite a quantidade de operações:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        fat = fat * i;
        soma += (x + i)/fat;
    }

    printf("A soma n pra S = x+n/n!\nÉ: %f", soma);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Na vdd o `fat` já começa com 1, então seria necessário apenas colocar sinal de atribuição para adição em `fat` também.

Comment: Mas colocando `fat +=` depois da soma o resultado é o mesmo, ele só inclui os outros `fat` já calculados anteriormente

Answer (score 0):

Bom, está aí minha resposta, o resultado deu no esperado

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    float x = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
    float soma = 0;
    int fat = 1;

    printf("Digite um valor:");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("Digite a quantidade de operações:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){

        soma +=(x + i)/fat;
        fat += fat * i;
    }

     printf("A soma de %.2f como x pra S = x+n/n!\nÉ: %.2f",x, soma);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Amigo o `%.2f` arredonda o valor pra cima, é só tirá-lo e vc vai ver o resultado não arredondado